# Having Trouble Getting a Array to read my text file

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get this array to read data from a text file and I can't seem how to get it too work at all . I have no clue whats wrong. I've never really done anything like this before can anyone help?

```
package students;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Students 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
          lines.add(sc.nextLine());
        }

        String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the exception you have!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams the problem in "words.txt" file location (I added this file in project location and it works).

So put your file either in your working dir, or provide full path or plase it in your classpath and retrive it as following

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("words.txt");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
```

to

```
String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
```

You have been setting your new string array to hold a single item instead of seting it to be the same size as your list.

Comment: This is approvment but it is not a reason to not work. It works even without this change. It set the size of list to 0, but if required necessary size the size of list increased automatically.

Answer (score 0):

May be your words.txt is not in the correct folder and it can't be found. Do you get an exception printed out?